# How to add form step validation in multi step jquery from (With radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using this exact sample code (Except I added 2 more form steps):

[LINK TO SAMPLE FORM](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Creating-A-Modern-Multi-Step-Form-with-jQuery-CSS3.html)

All my steps are radio buttons(Not Text Boxes) (2 radio buttons per form page). How can I validate the individual form pages so if no radio button is selected the form does not advance, and Ideally give user feed back to make the radio button selection? Right now the form will advance even if no field or selection has been made as it does in the demo. (See link above)

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `$(".next").click` function right under the next_fs variable declaration `next_fs = $(this).parent().next();` you could try something like the following:

```
if (current_fs.find('input:radio:checked').length == 0) {
    // Add error message handling here
    return false;
}
```

That will see if there are any radio buttons checked in the current frame and then cancel the button click event if there are none. You can also have an error message popup right before returning false.

I didn't re-create and test it, as trying to push myself to read that giant glob of code was painful enough, but I think that'll help you out. If it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Thanks Bryce, I'm giving it a shot right now! I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Tried it out and it stops working completely. No errors in console the next button just does not advanced with the code added. Heres a copy of the top portion of the script with the code I added:  $(".next").click(function () {
        if (animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

        if (current_fs.find('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
            // Add error message handling here
            return false;
        }

Comment: I'm sorry. It must be late. I thought you said checkboxes not radio buttons. I'll get the answer fixed

Comment: Give that a shot. Changed the selector from `input:checkbox:checked` to `input:radio:checked`

Comment: Thanks Bryce! we're getting close. You are required to have the radio button checked in order to move forward now. The only problem is: if you hit submit FIRST, and hit next the page will NOT move forward, then you select a radio button and hit next and the page will NOT move forward. so basically, if you do not have a radio button checked FIRST and hit next... selecting a radio button after will not work. So I need to refresh the page and start by making a selection in order to proceed. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: I got it! I had to add: current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next(); above the function we added. Thanks Bryce! Marked as resolved and your answer has been accepted. Thank you, was really struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "required" field ? That might help.
For Example:

input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Name" required

Comment: Well like I mentioned in the post above. I'm only using radio buttons (not text fields) and I did try a "required" attribute but as soon as you click the next button with the ".next" class the jquery script runs and it loads the next field set.